# React Component interface to methods

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, interface

Q: Is there any way to provide an interface to access public methods from a given reusable component?

Scenario: Imagine that I am buiding a `Tabs` component. It's located inside a parent component, called `App`:

```
<App>
    <Tabs />
    <button id="previous">Previous</button>
    <button id="next">Next</button>
</App>
```

As you can see there is two buttons that should interact with `Tabs` component, moving it to previous or next tab pane.

My implementation consists in keeping `next()` and `previous()` methods inside `Tabs` component:

```
export default class Tabs extends React.Component {
    next() {}
    previous() {}
}
```

Q: How can I bind `next()` and `previous()` methods to those buttons inside `App` component? Can I write some kind of interface exposed by `Tabs` component? What is the **best** and **clean** way to do that?

*Edit 1*: ...

*Edit 2*: `Tabs` is a "reusable" component. Many applications can render it inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others said, it doesn't make sense for your buttons to be outside your `Tabs` Component. 
The way I see your code sample, your `App` component should be your `Tabs` component, and I assume your `Tabs` component is representative of some sort of `TabsView`.

**app.js**

```
import Tabs from './components/tabs';

<App>
  <Tabs/>
</App>
```

**tabs.js**

```
class TabsView extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <span>{this.props.currentTab}</span>
    );
  }
}

class Tabs extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentTab: 0
    }
  }
  handleOnClickPrev(){
    this.setState({currentTab: currentTab--});
  }
  handleOnClickNext(){
    this.setState({currentTab: currentTab++});
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <TabsView currentTab={this.state.currentTab}/>
        <button id="prev" onClick={handleOnClickPrev.bind(this)}>-</button>
        <button id="next" onClick={handleOnClickNext.bind(this)}>+</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Tabs;
```

This way all the functionality of your component lives within it. The `Tabs` component now has all the information it needs. Each `Tabs` component you use will have its own state and tabs. If you want your currentTab state to come from the `App` so that you can render this same currentTab in other places you can pass it through from your `App` component as props.

**app.js**

```
<App>
  <Tabs currentTab={this.state.currentTab} handlePrev={} handleNext={}/>
</App>
```

**tabs.js**

```
class Tabs extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <TabsView currentTab={this.props.currentTab}/>
        <button id="prev" onClick={this.props.handlePrev}>-</button>
        <button id="next" onClick={this.props.handleNext}>+</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Tabs;
```

If you're looking to display Tabs in certain places and not the buttons in other places, you can use the `TabsView` component using that same prop that you passes down to the `Tabs` component.

**app.js**

```
<App>
  <Tabs currentTab={this.state.currentTab} handlePrev={} handleNext={}/>
  <TabsView currentTab={this.state.currentTab} />
</App>
```

If you're really hellbent on having your controls for the component live in different place than the component itself, I would suggest passing the same props down to both `TabsView` and buttons.

**app.js**

```
handlePrev() {
  this.setState({ currentTab: this.state.currentTab - 1 })
}
handleNext(){
  ...
}
render(){
  return (
    <App>
      <TabsView currentTab={this.state.currentTab} />
      <button id="prev" onClick={this.handlePrev.bind(this)}>-</button>
      <button id="next" onClick={this.handleNext.bind(this)}>+</button>
    </App>
  )
}
```

I don't think it makes sense for you to introduce Redux or any other state library at this point. Managing global state just for your tabs component is overkill.

Comment: Awesome. After some thinking this approach is more "reactive". Thank you! I ended up with this solution. <3

Answer (score 2):

You could get a [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-class-component) to Tabs instance in parent component

```
class Root extends Component {

  render() {
   return (
    <App>
      <Tabs ref={ref => this.tabs = ref} />
      <button id="previous" onClick={() => this.tabs.prev()}>Previous</button>
      <button id="next" onClick={() => this.tabs.next()}>Next</button>
   </App>
   )
  }
}
```

Or a more reasonble approach would be to switch to some centralized state management solution say Flux. Take a look at [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) :).

Answer (score 1):

If your buttons act on elements of the `Tab` component, then they should be inside this component. You can then easily change the `state` of your component with the `onPress` prop of the `Button`.

If you still want to keep your buttons outside of your component (*even if I don't see a clear reason for that*), then you should consider using a store like `Redux` to maintain a "global" state across your components.

Comment: Redux seems to mess it all when bringing global approach as solution. 
I mean, is it scalable? Shouldn't I keep `Tabs` actions inside `Tabs` context,  providing some kind of interface to handle this?

Comment: You just have to use Redux correctly. For example you'd have a `NavigationReducer` with actions like `GO_TO_NEXT_TAB` and `GO_TO_PREVIOUS_TAB`. But once again, for this use case, you should really embed your buttons inside your Tabs component since they are related to it.